# Meteor(React) : iOS application when enters to background(background running instance) all images disappears

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, amazon-s3, meteor-react

Created iOS application and running it on iphone-6 (iOS-application Meteor-ReactJS[version-1.6]).

When the application enters in to the background(background running instance) and when resumes to foreground, all the images from application disappears.
 Everything is working fine apart from display of the images. To see all the images all again I need to kill the application(i.e killing the background instance of application) from background and needs a fresh start.

I am saving images to Amazon-s3 using meteor-files. Not getting what is going wrong.

**UPDATE:**
Observed a application little and I came to know when there is a parameter in URL(eg./edit/:id using FlowRouter for the same). Then only images of subsequent/next components(pages/urls) are disappearing.

Possibly the same [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9293) posted. Also discussed in [meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-react-ios-application-when-enters-to-background-background-running-instance-all-images-disappears/40290).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's too broad. Could you show some code/templates?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i got you problem...You can use SDWebimage library for this...Once your  images get loaded...This Library stores your images in cache..Then you don't have to load images again for the entire life cycle of the App...Until you restart your App.
I hope this helps..Thanks

Comment: I will surely give a try. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. Need to look for same library in npm or something as I am working with hybrid environment and mentioned link is for native one.

Comment: Meteor(React) some what same as react native?

Comment: In React-native we use directly like

<ImageBackground
                    style={EstateDetailsStyles.PlaceImageStyle}
                    source = {{uri: rowData}}
                    defaultSource = {require('../../Assets/Images/hotel_image.png')}/>

Comment: we don't add any library for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the issues for both public folder as well as for S3 images. Afterwards I found that it was the issue related to relative and absolute path. So I changed the paths of all public images from '../images/xyz.png' to Meteor.absoluteUrl()+'../images/xyz.png'. And now its working fine for public folder images not yet tested for S3 yet.